# Remove SOAP envelope

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap

I have an InputStream containing a SOAP message, including the envelope. I don't know the contents of the body beforehand and therefore cannot create a Jaxb annotated class for it.

I've tried many ways, inlcuding a custom SOAPWrapper JaxB Class with XmlAnyElement and other ways. Currently I have this:

```
private InputStream removeSoapEnvelope(final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, TransformerException
    {
        final SoapBody body = messageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(inputStream)
            .getSoapBody();
        final Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
            .newTransformer();
        final DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();
        transformer.transform(body.getPayloadSource(), domResult);
        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(domResult.getNode()), new StreamResult(writer));
        byte[] barray = writer.toString()
            .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(barray);
    }
```

It seems to work but is horribly inefficient. Is there no short and concise way of achieving this with standard libraries and without regex?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the soap envelope of an xml message in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936068/how-to-remove-the-soap-envelope-of-an-xml-message-in-java)

Comment: Hi. Well I didn't want to use SimpleXMl nor String manipulation. I realize I could just do the regex but it's not the right way.  SimpleXml will also consume significant CPU and Memory as it parses it into a tree.  I edited the question to show that.

Comment: What inefficiencies are you talking about ? If you want a valid XML processing tool in the middle, then there's no way you can avoid some form of XML parsing and then serialization with your current "API" (taking and outputting an InputStream). So you can probably swap DOM with another XML API (e.g. SAX / StAX) and also output directly to bytes avoiding the string buffering, but I would not bet on it being a *huge* game changer (especially if your messages are a few kilo bytes).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using XPath to get the element (pure JaxB? not sure). Takes the document as a regular XML document so it should work for any I guess

```
FileInputStream fileIS;
fileIS = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/tmp/soap.xml");

DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document xmlDocument;
xmlDocument = builder.parse(fileIS);

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression01 = "//*[local-name()='Body']";
Node currentNode = (Node) xPath.compile(expression01).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);

StringWriter buf = new StringWriter();
Transformer xform = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes"); 
xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
xform.transform(new DOMSource(currentNode), new StreamResult(buf));
System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

Result:

```
<soap:Body>
        
    <incident xmlns="http://example.com">
                
        <Company type="String">Test</Company>
            
    </incident>
    
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it with regex. All other options are too slow:

```
private InputStream removeSoapEnvelope(final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    final String text = new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), UTF_8);
    final String replace = text.replaceAll("\\s*<\\/?(?:SOAP-ENV|soap):(?:.|\\s)*?>", "");
    File file = File.createTempFile("temp", XML_NS_PREFIX);
    Files.writeString(file.toPath(), replace);
    return new FileInputStream(file);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about the rationale here. You are agressively pushing for speed (e.g. you chose to forego XML processing, you skip charset detection, exposing your implementation to severe bugs for perfectly valid SOAP messages), but you write to the filesystem *and* read back without buffering *and* you do not precompile your regexp ? I understand XML processing has a cost but you still can go far faster than this solution, so why risk the bugs ?

Comment: Precompiling the regex is a good idea, just didn't think of it. I tried using ByteArrayOutputStream but go out of memory errors when converting the string in memory, that's why I write to the file first. Feel free to suggest alternatives.

Comment: sure I could suggest a faster XML valid solution, but it's hard to bench if we're not specific about what performance is here. For example, this answer surely is 2 to 5x more memory efficient than the DOM based (in the question), yet memory use was not an issue expressed in the question. We could also be more specific about the size + complexity (depth) of the XML (if the message is 1MB long, precompiling the regex is a negligible win!). And we'd have to know if its application/xml only, or also Swa / xop+mtom. Maybe you could add details about that in an edit to the question ?

Comment: The reason is that the XML to be processed is multiple 100s of MBs. I receive it from a Webservice and just get the InputStream from Apache HTTP Client.